# What is a rock solid and lightweight file manager to use with ubuntu 16.04 and Awesome WM?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, openbox, awesome

I have been using Awesome with Ubuntu and other Linux flavors as well for quite some time, it is all fine, nothing to complain, but tasks related to files sometimes can be managed faster using a file manager, I wonder what is the best file manager to use with Awesome, also it need to be rock solid (I mean no buggy!!) and lightweight as I stated in the title, just to say I do not like KDE, gnome it is okay, but to heavy for my machine. It is a low resources machine.

If it helps, I have installed Openbox Desktop (would be nice to call only the Openbox file manager in Awesome, but not sure how to do that), and sometimes I use it, but I prefer Awesome for many reasons.

I also found here some -> https://awesomewm.org/wiki/File_Managers (out of date I think) but I would like to go with Openbox if possible and avoid to install another package.

Comment: Impossible to answer. ALL software is bugged and the trick is to install one where  bugs are in parts you don't use ;-) -ALL- DE's should work on any system. Basically you can pick lUbuntu (LXDE) and xUbuntu (XFCE) if you system is low end. Mind that we ONLY supply official releases as answers.

Comment: Perhaps something LESS buggy. Since I have `LXDE` installed, I'm going with the standard `PCManFM`, and I avoid to install new packages, but the question still up and I would like to know from the user experience. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like two-pane window managers or any window managers that have the word commander in their name. All the other file managers at [File Managers - awesome](https://awesomewm.org/wiki/File_Managers) are either too heavy or else look ugly except for Rox-Filer and PCManFM.

Maybe Rox is more "rock solid" than PCManFM, but PCManFM wins the beauty contest. If Rox starts to behave like the asteroid belt, I'd say go with PCManFM.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a close look to `Rox-Filer`, it is new for me. I have `PCManFM 1.2.4` installed as part of `LXDE` and I'm using it right now, it is simple, remember-me an old windows system, but it does the job nicely. I'm really not paying to much attention to the looks, I want the functionality, but if it looks nice, it will be just a plus.